# I want to hardcode the value of a dummy column from my view created upon an oracle DB

Tags: view, oracle10g, crystal-reports-xi, dummy-data, hard-coding

I have a view which has one dummy column called action.
I have a formula {@action}

if {abc_view.name} startswith "abc" Then {abc_view.action} = "Represents action" Else {abc_view.action} = ""

and when I am calling this formula from the record filter section, all I get is 'action' under the dummy column action in crystal reports 2.0 for eclipse.
How do I achieve my purpose. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode the dummy column in oracle view while creating the view where COL1 and COL2 columns have actual value like the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ABC_VIEW
AS 
SELECT 
CASE WHEN name like 'ABC%'
THEN 'Represents action' 
ELSE
ACB.ACTION
END AS ACTION,COL1,COL2 FROM ABC;
```